# delete one level in a python dict keeping the values

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, python-3.x, dictionary

I have the following python dictionary:

```
'load_balancers': {'App': {'DJMatcher': {'security_group': 'sg-618d1c05', 'service_name': 'djmatcher/svc', 'certificateId': 'net', 'health_check_path': '/djmatcherstatus/ma.html', 'DNS': {'fde': {'record_name': 'platform-enrichment-djmatcher', 'ttl': 60}}}}}
```

Now it basically represents the following YAML:

```
 LoadBalancers:
    App:
        DJMatcher:
            certificateId: 'net'
            health_check_path: /djmatcherstatus/ma.html
            security_group: *svc_sg1
            service_name: *sn
            DNS:
                fde:
                    record_name: platform-enrichment-djmatcher
                    ttl: 60
```

I want to remove the second level of key - "App" and keep the rest as it is, which means the resulting python dictionary should become this where I delete the key App but the value now becomes the value for its parent key "load_balancers" :

```
'load_balancers': {'DJMatcher': {'security_group': 'sg-618d1c05', 'service_name': 'djmatcher/svc', 'certificateId': 'net', 'health_check_path': '/djmatcherstatus/ma.html', 'DNS': {'fde': {'record_name': 'platform-enrichment-djmatcher', 'ttl': 60}}}}
```

Any good way to achieve this ?

Comment: `d['load_balancers'] = d['load_balancers']['App']`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
derp['load_balancers'] = derp['load_balancers']['App']
```

Comment: I did : docs['load_balancers'] = docs['load_balancers'].pop(v.keys()[0], None) which worked, where v are the values.

Comment: Yeah but has a disadvantage. If you are only interested in one key of the v dictionary but it has more that one items, you get random results since dicts are not ordered! Your approach is basically "put from the first random item from 'load_balancers' of the v dict the first value into the docs dict"

Answer (score 6):

Although the problem does not ask for a general solution, I thought it might be worth working up one for the benefit of future searchers (and in case OP runs into a more complicated situation in the future).

```
def removeLevel(d, level):
    if type(d) != type({}):
        return d

    if level == 0:
        removed = {}
        for k, v in d.iteritems():
            if type(v) != type({}):
                continue
            for kk, vv in v.iteritems():
                removed[kk] = vv
        return removed

    removed = {}
    for k, v in d.iteritems():
        removed[k] = removeLevel(v, level-1)
    return removed
```

This runs recursively until it hits the correct level to remove, then copies all the children keys up.

For example:

```
>>> d = {'load_balancers': {'App': {'DJMatcher': {'security_group': 'sg-618d1c05', 'service_name': 'djmatcher/svc', 'certificateId': 'net', 'health_check_path': '/djmatcherstatus/ma.html', 'DNS': {'fde': {'record_name': 'platform-enrichment-djmatcher', 'ttl': 60}}}}}}
>>> removeLevel(d, 1)

{'load_balancers': {'DJMatcher': {'security_group': 'sg-618d1c05', 'service_name': 'djmatcher/svc', 'certificateId': 'net', 'DNS': {'fde': {'record_name': 'platform-enrichment-djmatcher', 'ttl': 60}}, 'health_check_path': '/djmatcherstatus/ma.html'}}}

>>> d2 = {'a': {'b':1, 'e':{'f':4}}, 'c':{'d':2}}
>>> removeLevel(d2, 1)

{'a': {'f': 4}, 'c': {}}

>>> removeLevel(d2, 0)

{'b': 1, 'e': {'f': 4}, 'd': 2}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
thedict['load_balancers'] = thedict['load_balancers'].pop('App')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dt[dt.keys()[0]] = dt[dt.keys()[0]].values()[0]
```

Comment: Don't forget about the randomness of the order of items in a dictionaries. If dt has more than 1 key the result of your approach changes each invocation.

Answer (score 0):

I found this question when trying to resolve a similar issue. Someone above gave a recursive method, but it uses Python 2 syntax, and only allows removing keys based on a "level" number, which didn't serve my purposes. Here's an example using a bit more modern syntax and allows for specifying keys to be removed:

```py
def remove_levels(in_dict, keys_to_remove):
    try:
        result = {}
        for key, value in in_dict.items():
            if key in keys_to_remove:
                result = {**result, **remove_levels(value, keys_to_remove)}
            else:
                result[key] = remove_levels(value, keys_to_remove)
        return result
    except AttributeError:
        return in_dict
```

You'd use it like:

```py
loadbalancers = {
    'LoadBalancers': {
        'DJMatcher': {
            'certificateId': 'net',
            'health_check_path': '/djmatcherstatus/ma.html',
            'security_group': '*svc_sg1',
            'service_name': '*sn',
            'DNS': {
                'fde': {
                     'record_name': 'platform-enrichment-djmatcher',
                     'ttl': 60
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
remove_levels(loadbalancers, {"App"})
```

Output:

```py
{'LoadBalancers': {'DJMatcher': {'certificateId': 'net',
   'health_check_path': '/djmatcherstatus/ma.html',
   'security_group': '*svc_sg1',
   'service_name': '*sn',
   'DNS': {'fde': {'record_name': 'platform-enrichment-djmatcher',
     'ttl': 60}}}}}
```